# Why do opioids administered via IV cause pruritus?

Tags: itching, post-surgical, intravenous, opioids-opiates

I was told by a nurse that it is common for patients to complain of itching after administration of IV opioids, which tends to resolve soon thereafter.  Those who experience this often do not experience it when taking the same medication orally.

***Why?***

- What about narcotics being administered IV causes pruritus?
- Is this a type of allergic reaction?
- What is chemically happening that causes the pruritus?
- Why doesn't this happen with the oral form?